# My chartreux stopped eating canned food - Normal?

Tags: cats, diet, eating

My 16 year old chartreux mix recently stopped eating his canned (wet) food.

I've always given him 100-200 grams each day and always had a bowl of dry food ready for him. Recently, he stopped eating the canned food and sticks with the dry food. I tried changing it to like 10 different brands, organic food (very expensive), and self made food. He just licks off the sauce and takes no bites anymore. I am in no worries about his health as he otherwise seems perfectly fine and he still eats (more now) dry food and drinks normally.

Is it maybe just a change in a cat's life? I heard you can buy just the sauce for cats so they can lick it off and get the fats and nutrients they need. Maybe that's an idea?

Comment: I wish I had an answer. My cat is just as picky. We can both take consolation in this -- we are most definitely not alone.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe he's just grown tired of the consistency of the food, or maybe he's had some experience with sickness or other unpleasant event that he associates with the wet food.

As long as the dry food provides for all the dietary needs I wouldn't worry too much, either try a minced wet food, or maybe leave wet food off the menu for a few weeks/months, then try again.

I'd mention the change in diet during your next vet visit, since a vet will be able to see it in a bigger context, though.